# Android & Robotium - Testing that a fragment shows up?

Tags: android, ui-automation, fragment, robotium

In my android application (Tablet) I want to verify that after selecting a button the fragment appears on the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a instance of the FragmentManager in your test since you have access to the activity. You can then either find the fragment by id or by tag and test that it is visible using the fragment method "isVisible" and assert that is set to true.

The javadoc for Fragment.isVisible() states **Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user.** This means the fragment has been added, has its view attached to the window, and is not hidden.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. Because, `Fragment.isVisible()` just indicates that the visible property is set on the fragment. For example, in `FragmentPagerAdapter`, when there are multiple fragments added, all the fragments have `isVisible()` as `true` which doesn't really mean all fragments are displayed to the user.